# Passing vector of unique_ptrs by reference

Tags: c++

This is more of a best practices type of question. Please assume that there are no issues with correctness.

Is it okay to pass around a vector of unique_ptrs by reference between functions in the same class? I want to do this to apply some changes to all the elements in the vector.

Related reason for confusion: [isocpp guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r33-take-a-unique_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-reseats-thewidget)

Example:
If I have a() calls b() calls c(), but some steps in b() should be done to only the first element in the vector, but I want to apply c() to all elements. Example:

```
a(){
  vector<unique_ptr<blah>> stuff;
  ...
  b(stuff);
}

b(vector<unique_ptr<blah>>& stuff){
  auto result = do_stuff_to(stuff.front().get());
  c(stuff, result);
}

c(vector<unique_ptr<blah>>& stuff, some_type result){
  ...
}
```

What would be a nicer/cleaner way? Thank you!

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Stuff{
    int a;
};

void c(vector<unique_ptr<Stuff>>& stuffs){
  for(const auto& stuff: stuffs){
      cout<<"c:"<< stuff->a<<endl;
  }
}

void b(vector<unique_ptr<Stuff>>& stuffs){
  cout<<"b:"<< stuffs.front()->a<<endl;
  c(stuffs);
}

void a(){
  vector<unique_ptr<Stuff>> stuffs;
  stuffs.push_back(std::make_unique<Stuff>());
  stuffs.push_back(std::make_unique<Stuff>());
  b(stuffs);
}

int main()
{
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without more details, this is unanswerable. There may be reasons not to do it in specific cases (usually related to reentrancy and threading, or in the case of `do_stuff_to`, perhaps misusing the unowned pointer it receives), but in the abstract, it's fine as is.

Comment: If we assume that passing by ref is by itself is safe and the 'stuff' from a() would not go away, would that simplify the question? I think I understand your answer and it is helpful. But would like to confirm.

I'm seeing guidelines mentioning not to pass unique_ptrs unless its done to pass ownership, and I am wondering how it applies to a vector<unique_ptr>. Creating another vector of raw pointers just to pass around seems unclean too?

Comment: You have a rep of nearly 400, you know now about the need to provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you believe the contents of the vector are significant for this question? (I.e. Why did you ask about "a vector of unique_ptrs" instead of more simply "a vector" or perhaps "a non-copyable vector"?)

Comment: Added a working example.

@JaMiT: This was because the I wanted to ask about passing unique_ptrs wrapped in containers. I know it works, but wanted to ask about best practices. Thanks!

Comment: @nahzor You have failed to indicate any reason to treat a vector of `unique_ptr` different than a vector of `int`. You know what you wanted to ask about, but you appear to have asked something different.

Comment: @nahzor Hmm... Maybe explain why you think there might be something wrong here? Maybe describe what do you not like about your current code?

Comment: @JaMiT: I am trying to understand how to think of a container of unique_ptrs with reference to [this guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r33-take-a-unique_ptrwidget-parameter-to-express-that-a-function-reseats-thewidget). I don't want to reseat, but would like to modify the contents of each 'Stuff'. And thank you for the back and forth.

Comment: @nahzor That guideline does not apply to your code sample as none of your functions take a smart pointer (directly) as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whereas from `std::unique_ptr<myType>`, we can easily use `/*const*/ myType*` or `/*const*/ myType&` when no ownership transfer is involved.

There are no trivial/simple types to represent the equivalent for range (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<myType>>`):

- transforming into `std::vector<myType*>` need extra vector.
- the lazy/range version `my_vec | ranges::transform([](std::unique_ptr<myType>& ptr){ return ptr.get(); })` is not a trivial type to write. Template or `auto` can still be used, but doesn't explain intent, we might have to add c++20 concepts to clarify it. But using template for "fixed" type has also its cons.

I don't see a winner from the 3 options.